# Send data with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a node.js server which emit data to my website.

I wrote a setInterval method to test if my client received correctly my json. Everything was ok. However when I comment my setInterval function, the client side receives nothing (newValues is called each 1s with a python script).

Here my node.js code :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    /*setInterval(function(){
      console.log("Fake!")
        socket.emit('dataCharts',
          JSON.stringify({
            validation : {nbValid: 1, nbUnValid: 2, total: 3},
            sira3d:{
              counterIn: 12,
              counterOut: 2
          }}
        ));
    },1000);*/

    socket.on('newValues', function() {
            console.log("new values");
      connection.query(sqlCountValid+";"+sqlCountUnvalid+";"+sqlSira3d, function(err,rows) {
        if(err) {
          console.log('Error connecting to Db');
          return;
        }

       // Create my variable obj ...

        var data = JSON.stringify(obj);
        if(data !== null && data !== undefined) {
          socket.emit('dataCharts', data);
          console.log("------> update data charts");
        }
        else
          console.log("data is undifined or null");
      });
    });
});
```

I don't know where is the problem.
Anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Are you sure you have the multiple statements option enabled when you set up the mysql database connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your server properly emitting the `newValues` event?

Comment: Find the solution I emited my message to my python script not to my web application -_-

Comment: Makes sense. Feel free to mark the question as resolved.